# Bad dataset layout

Tags: python, python-2.7, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I have three sets of 140+ dataset that are laid out in a weird way and I cannot figure out how to rearrange them with Python. The files are arranged with 4 rows on top and then 4 blanks lines followed by 5 columns. There are no headers, rows 1 and 2 are one column, row 3 is 2 columns, and row 4 is garbage. The first three rows are my identifiers for the dataset. Each data Set has multiple records. Example:

```
xx4 <--ID
070414 <--DateStrong
5.6 10 <--Force Ratio
Sample Rate:  50/s <--Garbage


220.68   0.14   17.80   92.20
220.80   0.02    9.40    9.40
224.32   0.14   14.60   72.20
227.08   0.14   26.60   130.60
227.78   0.08   19.60   62.00
228.04   0.18   40.40   257.20
231.22   0.12   14.00   61.20
```

I'm trying to arrange the set to be:

```
xx4, 070414, 5.6, 10, 220.68, 0.14, 17.80, 92.20
xx4, 070414, 5.6, 10, 220.80, 0.02, 9.40, 9.40
xx4, 070414, 5.6, 10, 224.32, 0.14, 14.60, 72.20
```

My current working code is:

```
import os
import sys
import csv
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import itertools as it
import benFuncts.BenFuncts as bf #My own functions
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ID = []

ID_dict = {}
DATE = []
FORCE = []
RATIO = []

TIME = []
DURR = []
pF = []
TOF = []

ED7 = []
ED6 = []
ED5 = []
ED4 = []

h = 'DATE', 'DAYNUM', 'RATIO', 'CRIT', 'TOTRESP', 'CRITRESP', 'PELLETS', 'AVG_PF', 'AVG_TOF'

Crit = {}


MastList = []
rd_files = []  # List of file strings


# Makes the main file path in this case:
# /Users/benlibman/Desktop/EffortDemandTests/EffortDemandPyTests/
path = str(os.getcwd()) + '/'

# List of files in the working directory (see path above)
mainDir = os.listdir(str(os.getcwd()) + '/')

# Pulls the list files from the mainDir (above)
ID = [i for i in mainDir if len(i) <= 3 and 'ED' in i]

# f_Out = csv.writer(open('MainFile', 'wa'), delimiter=',')
# f_Out = open('MainFile', 'wa')
# , quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
f_In = csv.reader(open('ED7',  'rb'), delimiter='\t')


def mkPath():
    for row in f_In:
        for i in row:
            if len(i) > 1:
                rd_files.append(path + str(i))

mP = mkPath()


# pdmF = pd.read_csv('MainFile', sep='\t', engine='python')
# with open('ED7120214', 'r') as f:


df = pd.read_csv(open('ED7120214', 'r'), sep='\t', skiprows=5, usecols=(
    0, 1, 2, 3), names=('TIME', 'DURR', 'pF', 'TOF'))

frCR = pd.read_csv(open('ED7120214', 'r'), sep=' ', skiprows=(0, 1, 3), skipfooter=(
    len(df)), engine='python', index_col=False, names=('FORCE', 'RATIO'))

date_index = pd.read_csv(open('ED7120214', 'r'), squeeze=True, sep=' ', skiprows=(
    0, 2, 3), skipfooter=(len(df)), engine='python', index_col=False, names=('DATE', 'NaN'))

id_index = pd.read_csv(open('ED7120214', 'r'), squeeze=True, sep=' ', skiprows=(
    1, 2, 3), skipfooter=(len(df)), engine='python', index_col=False, names=('ID', 'NaN'))


pDF = pd.DataFrame(df)

for row in pDF.TIME:
    TIME.append(row)

for row in pDF.DURR:
    DURR.append(row)

for row in pDF.pF:
    pF.append(row)

for row in pDF.TOF:
    TOF.append(row)

print pDF.pF.mean()

FORCE.append(frCR.FORCE)
RATIO.append(frCR.RATIO)

DATE.append(list(date_index.DATE))
ID_dict.update(id_index.ID)

DATE = [str(i).strip('[]') for i in DATE]

# ED7.append(FORCE)
# ED7.append(DATE)
# ED7.append(RATIO)
ED7.append(TIME)
ED7.append(DURR)
ED7.append(pF)
ED7.append(TOF)

Dt = bf.addCol(range(len(TIME)), DATE)


with open('MainFile', 'wa') as mf:
    pDF.to_csv(mf, header=True, index_names=True, names=(
        'DATE', 'DAYNUM', 'TIME', 'DURR', 'pF', 'TOF'))
```

Comment: Are you having a problem identifying a pattern that you can *capture* then rearrange?  Or have you figured that out but your code isn't working?  You should post your code and explain what is wrong with it and the things you have already tried to fix it so we don't duplicate your efforts.  Is there more than one *record* per file?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Sorry mine took so long. I am having trouble rearranging a pattern into a typical cols and rows format. Each files has upwards of 22,000+ rows

Comment: Is the final goal to write the data back to a file in the format you want?

Comment: That's the sub final goal. The final final goal is to grab each data set (each file) and summarize the PF, DURR, and TOF lines into a new file where the id, date, ratio, and force are identifiers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you are trying to do is reformat your data and write it back to a file, this should work for the file format in your example:

```
with open('data.txt') as in_file, open('new.txt', 'w') as out_file:
    # get the dataset identifiers
    ID = in_file.next().strip()
    date_strong = in_file.next().strip()
    force_ratio = in_file.next().strip()
    force_ratio1, force_ratio2 = force_ratio.split()
    in_file.next()  # Garbage line
    # example data has two blank lines
    in_file.next()
    in_file.next()
    dataset_id = (ID, date_strong, force_ratio1, force_ratio2)
    # iterate over the records
    for line in in_file:
        # prepend the dataset id
        record = list(dataset_id)
        record.extend(line.split())
        # write to the new file
        out_file.write(','.join(record) + '\n')
```